# How to understand "the way"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

"They echo the way they know the average juror speaks and thinks".

How to understand this sentence? "The way" seems to be the object of the verb "echo". But I cannot understand how " the way" is followed by a senetence directly.

Is this sentence correct grammatically? And if this is correct, how to understand the sentence?

Comment: *...and purposely attempt to relate to them at that level* [the sentence ends](https://books.google.com/books?id=BeDJ8Xtml9wC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=They+echo+the+way+they+know+the+average+juror+speaks+and+thinks&source=bl&ots=QxiRgtvkX3&sig=hNeYWmagoe2F3p5thUMwRI57uhw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ_NLJq_fNAhVPxCYKHUmgA-kQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=They%20echo%20the%20way%20they%20know%20the%20average%20juror%20speaks%20and%20thinks&f=false)

Comment: @AlanCarmack I omitted the part you mentioned since I thought we could understand the sentence without it. Is it essential part to understand the whole sentence?

Comment: Mainly, @MS.Kim,it is best to include in your question  a link to any sentence or text you have a question about. Very often context plays a key role in a sentence's meaning.

Comment: And, yes, having the complete sentence, and a link to it, makes it easier to understand the sentence, since it is a little strange standing on its own, especially since we do not who *they* are, and the verb *echo* is a bit weird here without any context to place it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's grammatical.

Here is how to understand it.
Let's assume that the average juror speaks and thinks in a certain way.
Here are the three clauses in your original sentence:

> 1) The average juror speaks and thinks that way.
>   2) They know (that) the average juror speaks and thinks that way.
>   3) They echo that way.

How can we combine 2) and 3) into a single sentence?
We can do that by joining the two clauses with *that*.
When we do this, *that way* in the main clause becomes *the way that [they know ...]*,
and the other *that way* in the subordinate clause must be deleted.

> 4) They echo **the way *that*** they know the average juror speaks and thinks **<del>that way</del>**.

Note that this *that* is usually omitted. What's left is your sentence:

> *They echo the way they know the average juror speaks and thinks*.

Comment: I understand. So far, I have thought at most only 2 two sentences could be combined with 'that'. Now I come to know more than 2 sentences can be combined. One more question. Is it usual to combine more than 2 sentences like the sentence in my question?

Comment: The technical term for those "sentences" inside a sentence is "clause". There is no limit to the number of clauses in a sentence. And though we don't always use compound or complex sentences, a sentence like yours is common enough. For example, Steve Jobs said this in his speech: *Your work is going to fill a large part of your life, and the only way to be truly satisfied is to do what you believe is great work, and the only way to do great work is to love what you do.* -- There are 6 (traditional) clauses in the two sentences.